# domain name different from business name

Tags: seo, user-friendly

Is it bad to have domain name little different from your business name?

For example: Business name is Houston Pharmacy while the domain name is Pharmacyhome.com

Would it be bad for SEO and also for user experience?

Comment: Have you considered getting the domain `houston.pharmacy`? As of this writing, it's open :)

Comment: @Sean that wouldn't be user friendly

Comment: @Muhammad it might not be so user friendly right now, but as people get more used to the new TLDs it will be.

Answer (score 2):

Many businesses have domains that differ from their established trade names. As long as your web pages are well put together to maximize SEO, there should be relatively little to no impact on prospective customers finding your site.

Answer (score 1):

I think having a domain name that is different from the company name can enhance user friendliness if the domain name is used in such away that appeals to the prospective viewer. It can be in the form of a short metaphor that users can quickly relate to or a brief description of the main service offered by the company.

Organising of key words and landing pages can be focused on to increase chances of an individual searching the internet for services the company offers and this is less likely to be affected by the different domain and company names.

Answer (score -1):

The EMD is one of the most important factor in SEO, however if your keywords is not the brand name then you can use that domain. It's not affect anything. When your brand name is more popular then people will search the brand, not the domain. IMO

Comment: Exact Matching Domains have not been an SEO factor for quite some time now.

Comment: It's still important in SEO man, I'm working on this and many results prove that.

Comment: Please share authoritative sources that indicate otherwise. As can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Google_Search) and [here](https://www.shoutmeloud.com/exact-match-domain-penalty-added-to-google-algo.html), announced by Matt Cutts in 2012, Google changed their algorithm to negate any advantage from EMD's. In fact, using them with low-quality content can result in penalties as well.

Comment: You're mentioning about low-quality content sites. Those site are useless in all ways. But for normal sites or high-quality sites, then with EMD is a strong point comparing to other sites. See [here](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/the-ultimate-seo-audit-checklist/196993/)

Comment: From that source: `most SEOs placing domain-level keyword usage at a minimum influence on rankings nowadays`, and `Sites that have an exact match domain but are a higher quality site will likely see a benefit from this.` There is nothing in that stating it's a "strong point", or "one of the most important factors in SEO" as you're asserting.